# How to search a comment in a project in phpstorm 8.0?

Tags: php, search, phpstorm

I am working on a PHP project using PHPSTORM 8.0. I commented in some files for documentation. Now I am trying to find the same string, its not showing me in search result. I use ctrl+shift+F key to find the commented string. I know its a way to search any string. but its not working for me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either you comment with "//" och "/*"..."*/". Search for that? What application are you coding in?

Comment: I am working on a web application and used "//" for comments. It works for the code but not for comment sting.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I get your question. You need to use regex for that. I don't know what code editor you're using, but I use Sublime Text which has support for regex.

This regex works for me:

```
//(.*?)$
```

So I just do CTRL+F and paste the line above in there. Make sure to toggle Regular Expressions when searching, otherwise it will look for that in pure text.